# Show tooltips when cell receives focus

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any way to have the tooltips display when a cell receives focus? If a user uses the keyboard exclusively to navigate then the tooltips do not display when the user tabs to a cell or navigates to it with the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

The built-in tooltip functionality is pretty basic, and not really customizable.
The only solution that I can think of is to write custom cell renderers that handle tooltips the way that you want.